# Copiar datos y formatos de una hoja de excel python

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente problema, cuando quiero copiar los datos de una hoja de excel y ademas sus formatos solo me copia los datos.

```
import pandas as pd

template = pd.read_excel('Template_sugerencia.xlsx', sheet_name='template')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Completo.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
template.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Recomendaciones', startcol=5, startrow=Recom_len, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente es así. El problema está en como **Pandas** usa el `writer` a Excel. Para poder mantener los formatos originales, a la hora de escribir por ejemplo una celda en particular, **Pandas** debería leerla en primer lugar y solo actualizar los datos planos de la misma, esto al menos uno de los `writers`, `openpyxl` lo soporta, y efectivamente así se hace en el método `write_cells()` sin embargo luego **Pandas** aplica sus propios estilos a la celda. Evitar o reconfigurar esto desde **Pandas** no parece tarea fácil.

Una solución alternativa es que escribamos nosotros mismos y no **Pandas** el `dataframe`. Por ejemplo de la siguiente forma:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path="test.xlsx"
sheet="Prueba"

# Leemos un archivo Excel al que le configuramos estilos
wb = load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)

# Generamos un dataframe con datos aleatorios
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('AB'))

# Iteramos por filas y celdas de un dtaframe
r = 2
for row in df.itertuples():
    cells = list(row)
    c = 1
    for cell in cells:
      # Actualizamos la celda de la planilla
      celldata = ws.cell(row = r, column = c)
      celldata.value = cell
      c += 1
    r +=1

# Salvamos finalmente el archivo
wb.save(path)
```

Esta es una prueba de concepto funcional. Deberías crear en la misma carpeta dónde corras el script, un archivo `test.xlsx`, dale el formato que quieras, por ejemplo algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego ejecuta el Script y deberías notar que los datos se "actualizan" y los estilos se mantienen. Es importante que entiendas que esta forma solo actualiza los datos desde una determinada fila y columna que le digamos hasta la última fila y columna del `dataframe`, si en la planilla original los datos tienen mas columnas o filas, no lo estaríamos controlando, lo deberíamos hacer y en todo caso eliminar estos. Esto también debiera funcionar par el caso de las formulas.

Más allá de esta respuesta, te comento que **Pandas** es muy flexible a la hora de dar estilos a las planillas, analizalo, tal vez te convenga más dar los estilos directamente desde **Pandas**.